# Useful Hudson spew for .NET and XCode?

Tags: email, hudson

I wanted to know if there was a specific plugin I could use to filter the output log from Hudson.

My engineers dont need the last 1000+ lines via email. I would like to specifically narrow down the failure to just the last couple. 
Regular expression or perl would help. 
Something like the warnings plugin would be great. (but instead of warnings, we would like errors instead.)

In addition, is there a way to customize the email template that hudson tends to send. I would like to get rid of the spew and just give people a link they can check out.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin)?